# Deleted over 60k emails on Gmail, space usage still the same

Tags: gmail, google-drive

I had 22GB of emails usage in Google. Then I went and deleted all emails bigger than 5M, then all with PPT or PPTX files. Then all from forums, promotions, updates and social. All in all over 60k emails. Now my usage is still showing 22GB and they want me to pay for more space. How can that be?

I also *did* delete the trash manually.

After some 30 minutes, the usage fell from 22GB to 18GB. So I managed to delete 4GB with 60k emails. However it's still strange that I have 18GB in only 20k emails, and 4GB in over 60k deleted emails.

Comment: The question is tagged with `google-drive`, so I have to ask:  Do you keep a lot of photos or movies on your google drive?  They are almost always the bulk of people's data.  A text email uses almost no space.  The PPTs use a little bit.  You essentially deleted 60K grains of sand from the beach when the large rocks are what are using your space.

Comment: This might be helpful: [How do I free up my Gmail's storage?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7054/354)

Comment: Storage is also shared among all google apps - photos and drive included, I think.

Answer (score 17):

It could take up to 24 hrs. to the storage meter to be updated.

**References**

- [Buy, change, or cancel storage plans - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375123?hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Google Drive/Images, your storage space is shared across all three applications.

You can check your photos account here: https://photos.google.com/

And Google drive here: https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive

Clearing down data in these areas should help.